# Tag Foursquare place using FB iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, foursquare

Overview: I want to take a Foursquare location and attach that to a FB OpenGraph object - *using the iOS SDK*. "John Smith ate pizza at /Patxi's Chicago Pizza/"

The FB API documentation only shows a 4SQ attachment using a straight URL approach: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#placeobjects

But the iOS SDK instructions don't show how to take a 4SQ URL, and associate that with a FB OpenGraph object. Is this possible?

I tried creating an FBGraphPlace, assigning the 'id' to be the 4SQ URL, and then attaching that GraphPlace to the OG Object, but FB ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the conditional and you should be able to do what you want

```
//if (self.selectedPlace) {
        // Facebook SDK * pro-tip *
        // We don't use the action.place syntax here because, unfortunately, setPlace:
        // and a few other selectors may be flagged as reserved selectors by Apple's App Store
        // validation tools. While this doesn't necessarily block App Store approval, it
        // could slow down the approval process. Falling back to the setObject:forKey:
        // selector is a useful technique to avoid such naming conflicts.
        [action setObject:@"https://foursquare.com/v/computer-history-museum/4abd2857f964a520c98820e3" forKey:@"place"];
    //}
```

[image: Posted to place]

Comment: This doesn't work, as FB rejects it as an incorrect FB ID. The only way this works if when 'place' is a URL param, not embedded into the Action

Comment: @beeudoublez pretty sure it works for me as noted by the screenshot that was made after an action using the sample build in the iOS simulator...